# Returning a value from completion block/closure used in datasource method

Tags: swift, closures, datasource

I have a custom view which is going to be displayed in the collection view. View will be added in a stack view embedded in a view controller. A data source method is exposed to provide a view object.

Now here is the problem, before adding my custom view to stack I need to make a gateway call first to check if it is allowed to display the view or not.
As gateway call is asynchronous and returns me the response in the callback. Based on callback I need to instantiate the view and return in data source callback provided.

Here is demo code just for better understanding. Forgive me for my terrible naming conventions.

```
func customeViewInStack(customView: UIView) -> [UIView]? {

        if viewIsAllowedToBeDisplayed {
            self.downloadViewContent(onCompletionHandler: { contentDownloadSuccessfull in
                if contentDownloadSuccessfull
                // Return new instance of my custom view
                else
                // return nil
            })
        }

        return nil
    }
```

All the suggestions I read were about using a closure to pass the value, but due to data source method and callback in gateway call, I need to use old fashion return statement.

**Edit 1**

**I have updated code snippet for better understanding.**
**I can not change function signature as it is part of a framework and a datasource method.**

Also this method is shared between different features. What I mean by that is different views going to get added in stack view and they have their own conditional check wether to add them or not.
So basically what I am trying to achieve is until i do not get response from gateway operation, program execution should not proceed ahead.
I have tried using DispatchGroup class, but not able to achieve my goal.

Can someone suggest me on how should I tackle this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

About that, the correct solution is to not return something from the function, but instead give a completion to that function.

```
func customeViewInStack(customView: UIView, completion: @escaping ([UIView]?) -> Void) {

    self.checkIfViewShouldBeShown(onCompletionHandler: { shouldDisplayView in
        completion(shouldDisplayView ? [...(put the stack of views to return here))] : nil)
    })
}
```

EDIT: I read it poorly first time, so I enhanced my answer.

As you need to pass it to collection view, I suggest that you will store it afterwards, and reload collection:

```
private var viewsForCollection: [UIView] = []

customeViewInStack(customView: UIView(), completion: { [weak self] views in
   self?.viewsForCollection = views ?? [] // I guess optionality for array is unnecessary
   self?.collectionView.reloadData()
})
```

At first, you will have an empty collection, but as soon as your views are ready, you can reload it.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I have updated my question. As I mentioned in my question I don't think closure will help my situation as I want program to wait till my closure gets executed.

Comment: As far as I know, anything you desire(synchronous waiting) will cause freezing the app. You can use sempahores for awaiting, but it will freeze the app. If you are using stack view, you can return view everytime and just show/hide the view after loading completes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare your own completion block and use that to get your new view:

Here is what that declaration looks like:

```
// Declaration
func customeViewInStack(customView: UIView, completion: @escaping ([UIView]? -> ()) {
    self.checkIfViewShouldBeShown(onCompletionHandler: { shouldDisplayView in
        if shouldDisplayView
            // Call the completion block with the views
            completion(views)
        else
            // Call the completion block with nil
            completion(nil)
    })
}
```

And then in your usage of this, you would use it just like you used the `checkIfViewShouldBeShown` method:

```
customViewInStack(customView: customView, completion: { views in
    guard let views = views else {
        // Views are nil
    }

    // Do what you need to do with views
})
```

Comment: I can not modify method signature so using a closure in there is not a option for me. Its a datasource method and different features going to use same datasource.

Comment: Using a completion block shouldn't hinder your ability to use this method in different locations...